# Alterando valor do model por JQuery e Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho um model onde tenho o atributo `status`, este atributo eh um `int` que defino valores. No meu form tenho 2 botoes: `gravar e publicar` e `gravar`, cada um desses botoes seriam um valor para o status, no caso o `gravar e publicar` tem valor 1 e o `gravar` valor 0.

Para definir esses valores estou tentando usar o JQuery e alterar o valor do model quando faz o submit, verificando qual botao foi clicado para alterar o valor do `status`, mas não estou conseguindo.

Como posso fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

**html**

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Gravar e Publicar" id="gravarPublicar"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Gravar" id="gravar" />
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addPropriedade').submit(function () {
        //var dados = $(this).serialize();
        var dados = new FormData($('#addPropriedade').get(0));

        $('#gravarPublicar').click(function () {
            dados.status = 1;
            console.log(dados.status);            
        });
        $('#gravar').click(function () {
            dados.status = 0;
            console.log(dados.status);            
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addPropriedade').submit(function () {
        //var dados = $(this).serialize();


        $('#gravarPublicar').click(function () {
           '@Model.status' = 1;
            console.log('@Model.status');            
        });
        $('#gravar').click(function () {
              '@Model.status' = 0;
            console.log('@Model.status');            
        });
```

Comment: não funciona, da o seguinte erro: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`